# understanding complexity of a function with defined function

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity

this is the algorithm :

```
F() = {
  count = 0
  n = 1000
  For i = 1 to n Do
   If n Modulo i = 0 Then
     count = count + 1
   end if
  end for
  if count = 2 then
   return prime
  else return prime
}
```

So what i know is complexity of a loop is n and other than loop is some constant

so what i get is O(n)

but my teacher said its O(1) because the n is already defined

is my teacher correct ?

Thank you in advance :)
Sorry for my bad english

Comment: (`Sorry for my bad english` Prefer getting help, if by a machine, over begging for leeway: Let a spelling checker assist you. For text decoration, see the post editor help.) (When communicating for a purpose, investing appropriate effort should suffice. Never mind perfection (unless you're a professional writer using your 1st language).)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your teacher is correct. We measure the complexity with respect to *the input*'s size.

Here, you don't have any input to the function, and $n$ is just a constant defined within the function.

Thus, the loop runs only a constant number of times, which is $O(1)$.